# How to find what mounted volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have next service at docker compose file:

```yaml
  prometheus:
    depends_on:
     - promscale
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

At `portainer` I can see that this service mounted at `/prometheus`:
[image]

**But I can not understand where is definition for this mount and where it is mounted?**

I can not find, neither at host or at container, `/prometheus` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is inside Dockerfile https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/Dockerfile#L23 :

```
VOLUME     [ "/prometheus" ]
```

Comment: Ok. So this is named volume, used by prometheus internally to store persistent data for this container.